# Extract single field from string in android emulator environment

Tags: text-processing, awk, android

I am running android emulator with the `adb` shell

I try to extract the field `_id=number` from a query output.

- The "raw" result looks like:

  ```
  Row: 9991 last_time_contacted=0, phonetic_name=NULL, custom_ringtone=NULL, contact_status_ts=NULL, pinned=0, photo_id=NULL, photo_file_id=NULL, contact_status_res_package=NULL, contact_chat_capability=NULL, contact_status_icon=NULL, display_name_alt=+90532555688, sort_key_alt=+90532555688, in_visible_group=1, starred=0, contact_status_label=NULL, phonebook_label=#, is_user_profile=0, has_phone_number=1, display_name_source=40, phonetic_name_style=0, send_to_voicemail=0, lookup=0r10070-24121C1814241820221C1A14.3789r10071-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10072-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10073-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10074-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10075-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10078-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10082-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10083-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10084-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10085-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10086-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10087-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10092-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10094-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10097-24121C1814241820221C1A14, phonebook_label_alt=#, contact_last_updated_timestamp=1612984348874, photo_uri=NULL, phonebook_bucket=213, contact_status=NULL, display_name=+90532555688, sort_key=+90532555688, photo_thumb_uri=NULL, contact_presence=NULL, in_default_directory=1, times_contacted=0, _id=10097, name_raw_contact_id=10070, phonebook_bucket_alt=213
  ```
- I would like to extract the string `_id=10097` from the above output.
- My attempt so far:

  ```
  content query --uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts | grep "+9053158888" |   awk -F'[,,= ]' '{cmd="content delete --uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts/"$(NF-3);system(cmd)}'
  ```

But it doesn't find the string.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the same question is posted on multiple sites and the OP has already accepted an answer to this at https://stackoverflow.com/q/66153426/1745001.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A portable solution:

```bsh
$ grep -o "[[:blank:]]\+_id=[^,]*" | sed 's/^ //'
_id=10097
```

---

If you have [GNU grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) available, with [`lookbehind assertion`](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2syntax.html#SEC19):

```bsh
$ grep -Po "(?<=[^a-z])_id=[^,]*"
_id=10097
```

Comment: i have error usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoPqRSsUVvwxZz] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
        [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
        [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
        [pattern] [file ...]

Comment: @tolgatasci please edit your question and mention the operating system you are using. Don't use tags for this, say it with words so it is obvious.

Comment: okey i edit now

Comment: @tolgatasci I don't have access to android, see my updated answer.

Comment: thank you fixed